# AttributeError: 'SubRequest' object has no attribute 'param' trying to get parameters within fixture from @patest.mark.parametrize()

Tags: python, pytest

this is the function from a test module:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
        'x,y', [
            ('x', 'y'),
        ], indirect=True)
    def test_smthng(self, entity, x, y):
        pass
```

and this is my fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture
def entity(request):
    entity = request.param
    ...
```

and I'm getting AttributeError: 'SubRequest' object has no attribute 'param'
at the first line of the fixture body.
Could someone help to understand why?
pytest==7.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was my mistake, parameters x, y are incorrect it should be named 'entity' like the fixture name